# Differentiating between sent and received mail

Tags: php, email, imap

I am using  the below code to can through my inbox:

```
$imap = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/ALL Mail", $yourEmail, $yourEmailPassword);
```

The thing is how to segregate between the sent mails and recieived mail?

I know I can use:

```
imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail", $yourEmail, $yourEmailPassword);
imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX", $yourEmail, $yourEmailPassword);
```

But the thing I want to do this?

I want to extract mail using `ALL MAIL` and while iterating i should know if it is a sent or received?
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I guess sent mail is where your E-Mail is in the `from` field. Maybe you can filter for that?

Comment: No,every header has both from and to field.You can't do from that.

Comment: You'll need to extract the labels for the email, which is a gmail extension. Read the gmail extensions for IMAP document. (All Mail is also a gmail extension)